# Get specific route in CakePHP 2 Paginator

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 4 routes to same controler/action.

```
Router::connect('/noticias/:id/:slug/*', array(
    'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'listing', 'admin' => false),
    array(
        'pass' => array('id','slug'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
        'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
    )
);

Router::connect('/servicos/:id/:slug/*', array(
    'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'listing', 'admin' => false),
    array(
        'pass' => array('id','slug'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
        'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
    )
);

Router::connect('/aplicacoes/:id/:slug/*', array(
    'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'listing', 'admin' => false),
    array(
        'pass' => array('id','slug'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
        'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
    )
);

Router::connect('/produtos/:id/:slug/*', array(
    'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'listing', 'admin' => false),
    array(
        'pass' => array('id','slug'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
        'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
    )
);
```

But, when I try generate pagination of these differente routes, CakePHP generate just for the first (found) route in routes.php file.

How can I get specific route? Or set the route **manually** in Paginator?

**WHAT** is the best solution for this? Create 4 actions? Regex? Redirect?

---

```
<div class="paging right">
    <?php $this->Paginator->options(array(
        'url'=> array(
            'controller' => 'posts', 
            'action'     => 'listing',
            'id'         => $this->params->pass['0'],
            'slug'       => $this->params->pass['1'],
            'admin'      => false
        )
    )); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('<' . __(''), array(), null, array('tag' => 'a', 'separator' => '')); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '')); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('') . '>', array(), null, array('tag' => 'a', 'separator' => ''));  ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd param array is the same for all 4 routes. So how do you expect cake to distinguish which url string to generate when reverse routing? It will always use the first matching one. Choose better, logically distinguishable routes.

Comment: Yes, I know that ADmad. CakePHP use the first route found. My question is: what is the best solution for this? Create 4 actions? Redirects? What? Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: Different actions would be a sensible way.